# list.add() does not add data to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to add data to ArrayList object. In my code addBook() method will be show Input Dialogue Box and pass this string to isbn variable. Now there is need to add isbn variable data to ArrayList which is reside in BookInfoNew() constructor but list object not found in addBook() method. (list.add(isbn))

kindly help me.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class BookInfoNew {
    private static String isbn;
    private static String bookName;
    private static String authorName;
    public static int totalBooks = 0;

    //default constructor
    public BookInfoNew() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); //create ArrayList
    }

    //Parameterized constructor
    public void BookInfoNew(String x, String y, String z) {
        isbn = x;
        bookName = y;
        authorName = z;
    }

    //add book method
    public void addBook() {
        String isbn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter ISBN");

        //add books data to ArrayList
        list.add(isbn);
    }
}
```

Comment: because `list` is a local variable, which only exists in your non parameter constructor.

Comment: Why are the other fields `static`?

Comment: your question title is erroneous , since your `addBook()` doesn't even have access to `list`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an issue with scope. You cannot access your `list` object within the `addBook()` object. So, you have to either make `list` a parameter to `addBook()` or you can make it a global variable.

This code fixes it using a global variable:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class BookInfoNew {
    private String isbn;
    private String bookName;
    private String authorName;
    public int totalBooks = 0;

    // global list variable here which you can use in your methods
    private List<String> list;

    //default constructor
    public BookInfoNew() {
        list = new ArrayList<String>(); //create ArrayList
    }

    //Parameterized constructor - constructor has no return type
    public BookInfoNew(String x, String y, String z) {
        isbn = x;
        bookName = y;
        authorName = z;
    }

    //add book method
    public void addBook() {
        String isbn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter ISBN");

        //add books data to ArrayList
        list.add(isbn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code has been edited. As @manu asked, why are your other variables static?

Comment: Now list.add(isbn) is not working. it says list.add(isbn) method is undefined.

Comment: its works well when list.add(isbn) will in BookInfoNew() constructor

Comment: If you want to run `addBook()` every time you create a new `BookInfoNew` object, you can just write `addBook()` in the constructor.

Comment: And maybe you should remove the `String` in front of `isbn` in the `addBook()` method. That way you would be updating the instance variable `isbn` and not a local variable.

Comment: import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;;

public class BookInfoNewMain {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  BookInfoNew obj = new BookInfoNew();
  
  obj.addBook();
  
 }
}

Comment: its my main method sorry i am unable to properly format code

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite your code a little bit like that:

```
...
List<String> list = null;
public BookInfoNew() {
    list = new ArrayList<String>(); //create ArrayList
}
...
```

and it should be ok.

Comment: No need for `= null;`